# Passing select value to Input name

Tags: php, html, laravel, select, input

I want to pass the value getting from select (value e.g. 1 or 2) as a name for the input type (id="store").
Is this possible in any way? I am trying to use this code in Laravel frontend.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="projectinput5" name="interested" class="form-control">
        <option value="" selected>Select item</option>
        <option value="1">RED</option>
        <option value="2">Blue</option>
    </select>
<input id="store" type="text" name=" ">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to ask here, can you try and improve your question please

Comment: A better question is *why*? Why not just send the select value to the server instead of changing the name of the text input?

Comment: The reason am doing this is because to display only one form elements dynamically instead of coding for multiple inputs based on real-time actions

Comment: Please see [ask]. Tell us what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with javascript:

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.getElementById('projectinput5').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            var value = e.target.value;
            document.getElementById('store').setAttribute('name', value);
            console.log('#store name is now: ' + document.getElementById('store').getAttribute('name'))
        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="projectinput5" name="interested" class="form-control">
        <option value="" selected>Select item</option>
        <option value="1">RED</option>
        <option value="2">Blue</option>
    </select>
<input id="store" type="text" name=" ">
</div>
```

Comment: This is actually brilliant, I didnt know that was possible.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.
Most of the developer doesn't know that this simple thing can be done.